# Error using babel-relay-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, relayjs

I stumbled upon an error while using babel-relay-plugin.

When I require babel-relay-plugin module and export the output with my graphql schema and call it in my webpack list of babel plugins as a path works.

```
// webpack/plugins/babel-relay-plugin.js
var babelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
var schema = require('./../../cloud/data/schema.json');

module.exports = babelRelayPlugin(schema.data);


// webpack/pro.config.js
    module.exports = [
      {
        module: {
          loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loader: 'babel',
              query: {
                plugins: [
                  './webpack/plugins/babel-relay-plugin'
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }

    }
]
```

But when I create the plugin in the same file as this:

```
// webpack/pro.config.js
var BabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
var schema = require('./../cloud/data/schema.json').data;

module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: cloudPath,
    output: {
      path: buildPath,
      filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            plugins: [
              new BabelRelayPlugin(schema)
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

It throws this error stack:

```
ERROR in ./cloud/index.js
    Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of null
        at Function.normalisePlugin (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:156:20)
        at /Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:197:30
        at Array.map (native)
        at Function.normalisePlugins (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:173:20)
        at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:271:36)
        at OptionManager.init (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:416:10)
        at File.initOptions (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
        at new File (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
        at Pipeline.transform (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
        at transpile (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
        at Object.module.exports (/Users/AJ/Desktop/winebox/app/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:88:12)
```

Any pointers as to how fix this inside the same file would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

All my packages are up-to-date an I already asked and it's not a Relay-side problem.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue that was faced by OP, the solution provided by @steveluscher raised `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined`.

There is a plugin [babel-plugin-react-relay](https://github.com/graphcool/babel-plugin-react-relay) that solves this problem. It can take a json file, URL or `graphql-js` schema.

It relies on `babel-relay-plugin` so that you do not have to create your own plugin.

Usage is simple:

`npm install --dev babel-plugin-react-relay`

In your `.babelrc` file, add:

```
"plugins": [
  "react-relay"
],
```

In `package.json`, add the path to your schema:

"react-relay-schema": "./data/schema.json"

And if you're using `webpack`, specify the plugin under `babel-loader` for your loaders:

```
{
    test: /\.js?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    ],
    query: {
        plugins: ['react-relay'],
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
 }
```

Comment: I believe since babel-plugin-react-relay switched to graphql-config,  you add to package.json: "graphql": {
      "file": "./schema.json"
   }  This according to https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-config#usage

Answer (score 1):

`require('babel-relay-plugin')` returns a function that you can use to get a plugin given a schema. I think the usage that you're looking for is:

```
// webpack/pro.config.js
var babelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
var schema = require('./../cloud/data/schema.json').data;

module.exports = [
  {
    /* ... */
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            plugins: [
              new (babelRelayPlugin(schema))()
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The inner expression returns a plugin, while the outer expression creates an instance of that plugin using the `new` keyword.

Comment: The above doesn't work for me, @steveluscher. It generates this error: `/home/varun/Code/opencurriculum/oc_platform/node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/lib/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:47
    var Plugin = _ref.Plugin;`

Comment: Did this solve your problem at least, @AJ_1310, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble into this and are getting this error:

```
/app/client/node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/lib/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:53
    var Plugin = _ref.Plugin;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (/app/client/node_modules/babel-relay-plugin/lib/getBabelRelayPlugin.js:53:22)
```

Here is how the config I used to fix it:

at the root of my client app: `babelRelayPlugin.js`

```
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');

// Make sure the path is correct here
const schemaData = require('../data/schema.json');

module.exports = getBabelRelayPlugin(schemaData.data);
```

Then in my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["./babelRelayPlugin"]
}
```

Here are my dependencies in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "0.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-relay": "0.10.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.10",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.68.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^v2.0.0-rc.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-cleanup-plugin": "^0.4.2",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1"
  }
```

I believe the babel `stage-0` preset is required as it is present in all configs that work but I can't say for sure