# I get warning message "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" when starting react app

Tags: reactjs

When i start my react app. I get two warning message as:

> `WARNING in ./node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js 61:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

> `WARNING in ./node_modules/import-fresh/index.js 27:32-49 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

I'm not sure how to handle this, because this is issues of packages in node_modules.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "extends": "./tsconfig.path.json",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "typeRoots": ["src/types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out", "dist", "build"],
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.tsx", "craco.config.js", ".eslintrc.js"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@emotion/css": "11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.16",
    "@giantmachines/redux-websocket": "1.5.1",
    "@redux-devtools/serialize": "0.3.0",
    "@types/query-string": "6.3.0",
    "antd": "4.17.4",
    "axios": "0.26.1",
    "chardet": "1.4.0",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "content-disposition": "0.5.4",
    "craco-alias": "^3.0.1",
    "craco-less": "^2.0.0",
    "currency.js": "2.0.4",
    "dnd-core": "14.0.1",
    "dotenv": "10.0.0",
    "file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "html-react-parser": "1.4.8",
    "i18next": "21.6.11",
    "immutability-helper": "3.1.1",
    "immutable": "4.0.0",
    "js-file-download": "0.4.12",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "query-string": "7.1.1",
    "rc-animate": "3.1.1",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-cool-virtual": "0.7.0",
    "react-dnd": "14.0.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "3.1.4",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "0.17.0",
    "react-hook-form": "6.15.7",
    "react-i18next": "11.15.5",
    "react-mentions": "4.3.0",
    "react-number-format": "4.9.3",
    "react-process-string": "1.2.0",
    "react-query": "3.34.16",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "react-select": "5.2.2",
    "react-transition-group": "4.4.2",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
    "redux-localstorage": "0.4.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "redux-saga-thunk": "0.7.3",
    "require-context.macro": "1.2.2",
    "rollbar": "2.24.0",
    "scroll-into-view": "1.16.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.5",
    "url-regex-safe": "2.1.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "8.1.1",
    "use-debounce": "7.0.1",
    "uuid": "8.3.2"
  }
```

**devDependencies**

```
{
    "@parcel/reporter-bundle-analyzer": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-less": "2.8.3",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "2.8.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "@types/classnames": "2.3.1",
    "@types/content-disposition": "0.5.4",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.12",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.179",
    "@types/node": "17.0.26",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.11",
    "@types/react-helmet": "6.1.5",
    "@types/react-highlight-words": "0.16.3",
    "@types/react-mentions": "4.1.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.2",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "4.4.5",
    "@types/redux-immutable": "4.0.3",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "1.0.3",
    "@types/resize-observer-browser": "0.1.7",
    "@types/scroll-into-view": "1.16.0",
    "@types/url-regex-safe": "1.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.55.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.55.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.20.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "coveralls": "3.1.1",
    "craco-less": "^2.0.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.6.2",
    "eslint": "^8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.2.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-turbo": "^0.0.9",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "4.18.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "2.0.3",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "less-plugin-autoprefix": "2.0.0",
    "msw": "0.36.3",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "0.3.7",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "parcel": "2.2.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "pm2": "5.1.2",
    "prettier": "2.8.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "4.0.1",
    "sass": "1.53.0",
    "stylelint": "^15.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^30.0.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.5.0",
    "swagger-typescript-api": "^12.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "3.5.2"
  }
```

Can you guys help me? Thank you very much

**UPDATE**: I tried `yarn upgrade` and deleted node_modules and reinstalled but the warning is still showing

Comment: These warnings are for critical dependencies that are used in a way that cannot be statically extracted. You can try these steps: Update your dependencies by running `npm update`. Use the latest version of `babel-plugin-macros` by running `npm install babel-plugin-macros@latest`. Check if the newly imported package is outdated. If so, you can find an alternative package or update the code to not use this package.

Comment: @MahdiSamavi I tried your way, even deleted node_modules and reinstalled but the warning is still showing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade or downgrade versions of packges in package.json. And, post package.json in your question for better grasp.

EDIT: I added these sites links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35108839/) and this too [link2](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/issues/326) to resolve this error.